# Check Time Overlap In SQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net, sql-server

I am trying to check two interval of time, the first is know in the code as two DATETIME instances **Start_Time** and **End_Time** , and the second interval i retrieve from the database, **How i can check for Minutes in case the Hours are equal**, here is what i am trying to write

```
   Select * FROM MY_TABLE 
   WHERE " ( "+ Start_Time + "<= IF(HOUR(DB_End_Time)=0, 24, HOUR(DB_End_Time) ) AND" +
         " IF(HOUR(DB_Start_Time)=0, 24, HOUR(DB_Start_Time) ) <= " + End_Time + " ) "+
         " OR "+
         " ( "+ Start_Time +"<= IF(HOUR(DB_Start_Time)=0, 24, HOUR(DB_Start_Time))AND " +
         " IF(HOUR(DB_End_Time)=0, 24, HOUR(DB_End_Time) ) <= " + End_Time+" ) ;"+
```

I tried things like Between and >= <= for the datetime it self , but it keep getting me an error and ask to check sql version!

This works fine with hours, any one knows how to include IF statement or something to get it work fine with minutes as well !?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: mysql or sql-server?  And post the net query.  Don't make us try an parse out the the tsql from that.

Comment: And not to forget: *use parameterized queries*!

Answer (score 1):

If you have actual datetimes to work with, I think you are making this too complicated by trying to isolate hours, minutes, seconds, etc.

Try something of this nature:

```
select *
from MY_TABLE
where @Start_Time < DB_End_Time
    and @End_Time > DB_Start_Time
```

This will check for any *overlap*, but not for consecutive intervals. As in, I don't think 10-11 and 11-12 overlap, but you can change `< ... >` to `<= ... >=` to account for that if you wish.

Also, as has been mentioned, please use a parameterized query from your app rather than your concatenated string which is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.